# How to show the overlay of an object on an image with only borders in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, image-segmentation

I saw a very nice representation of overlaying results on image in a paper and trying to do a similar approach on my data. Here ground truth is the object overlayed with red borderlines and segmentation result is with green color.

[image]
I have 3 images: MRI, ground truth (gt) and results obtained from an algorithm (res). How should I write the code for this similar representation in python? Or if there is any free code available to use, please share here. 
Thanks

Comment: here are some existing implementations from matplotlib,skimage:
1) https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html
2) http://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_boundaries.html
3) https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ground-truth and `res` are 2D masks, you can create a RGB image from your grayscale image and change the color of pixels where `res` indicates to. Here is an example of highlighting edges extracted using Canny edge detector on a [sample](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cunha/images/brain.png) image:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('brain.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,200)   # canny edge detector

img = cv2.merge((img,img,img))  # creat RGB image from grayscale
img2 = img.copy()
img2[edges == 255] = [255, 0, 0]  # turn edges to red

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img2)
plt.title('Edge Highlighted'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, I have three images now, one grayscale MRI image (384x384), one gt (384x384x3: boundary with red color and background 0), and one res (384x384x3: boundary with blue color and     background 0). How to overlay them in one image? thanks again

Comment: `MRI = cv2.merge((MRI, MRI,MRI)); MRI[gt[:,:,2] ==255] = [0, 0, 255]; MRI[rea[:,:,0] ==255] = [255, 0, 0]`

Comment: When I am doing this line, it is only showing the MRI not the segmentation results nor gt

Comment: I do not have `gt` and `res`, but thi may work: `MRI = cv2.merge((MRI, MRI,MRI)); MRI[res[:,:,2] > 0] = [0, 0, 255]; MRI[gt[:,:,0] > 0] = [255, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Masoud the first one is more correct, however, when I am adding the second color map, the previous one is disappeared. For example, if I run `MRI[gt[:,:,2] ==255] = [0, 0, 255]` , and then I run this `MRI[rea[:,:,0] ==255] = [255, 0, 0]`, it will show the last one not both of them.

Comment: Thats because `res` override `gt` (they overlap). Shows the algorithm is doing great!

Comment: How to tackle this then? Thanks. I want both on MRI

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ground truth is a binary segmentation mask,
this [skimage find contour](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-contours-py) should work. Multiple contours may be found and you can choose to only plot one of them. Set different values for parameter 'level' to extract contours from multiclass segmentation mask.